# Homebrew: PATH env var is modified before installation of Formulae (mercurial will use system python instead of homebrew python)

Tags: python, macos, path, mercurial, homebrew

Trying to use Homebrew on Mac OS X 10.9 to install mercurial and make sure it's using homebrew python version.

I've updated `/etc/paths` to list `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

Installed python 2.7.9 using `brew install python`, the python executable is located at `/usr/local/bin/python` which is a symlink to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/python`.
When I type `which python` or `python -V` I'm getting the homebrew python version.

Later, when I run `brew install mercurial` the installed file `/usr/local/bin/hg` shebang (`#!`) points to the system python `/usr/bin/python`.
This is happening because mercurial python package installer (distutils) is using the PATH variable to hardcode the path to python in shebang instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

When I check my PATH environment variable I see `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, but if I try to install a brew package interactively: `brew install -i mercurial` I get a shell with a different PATH variable without `/usr/local/bin` at all.

How can I install mercurial to make sure it will use the homebrew version of python ?
I prefer a way that would survive mercurial package upgrades as well.

Comment: Why do you want mercurial to use Homebrew's python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the formula only uses system Python. You can bypass Superenv (which sanitizes PATH) and it should pick up whatever is in PATH when building from source:

```
$ brew reinstall mercurial --build-from-source --env=std
$ head -n 1 /usr/local/bin/hg  
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
```